# Playframework giving error in dynamic route

Tags: java, playframework

I'm trying to make an application using Play and I'm getting an error with one of my dynamic routes so my application isn't compiling. I read the documentation [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaRouting) and it looks like I'm doing everything correctly.

Below is the line in my routes file that is giving me the error.

```
POST    /user/delete/:id            controllers.MainController.deleteUser(:id Long)
```

Below is the controller that is being called in the routes file.

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class MainController extends Controller {

    public static Result index() 
    {
        return ok(views.html.index.render("Hello from Java"));
    }

    public static Result users()
    {
        return TODO;    
    }

    public static Result newUser()
    {
        return TODO;    
    }

    public static Result deleteUser(Long id)
    {
        return TODO;
    }

}
```

It keeps on telling me conf/routes:10: Compilation error[`)' expected but`:' found]

Answer (score 2):

Colon in the method signature isn't placed correctly. It should be:

```
POST    /user/delete/:id            controllers.MainController.deleteUser(id: Long)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake, but I still get the same error after making the correction that you pointed out.

Comment: Stop play and run "play clean run". Also check other routes as well for the same mistake.